# Tikz "none at all" style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm creating a customisable TikZ pic where I want to enable or disable certain parts of it (e.g. some labels).
Is there a style that I can pass to a node, pic, path or so that doesn't visibly draw it?
So basically like `draw=none`, except that it should also extend to `text`, `fill` and so on.

One first try would be `\tikzset{none/.style={draw=none,fill=none,text opacity=0}}`, but I can't believe there is no "proper solution" for this. Maybe there is, and I just don't know which style to look for.

See for example how my first try could be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bla/.pic={\node {A};},none/.style={draw=none,fill=none,text opacity=0}]
        \pic at (0,0) {bla};
        \pic[none] at (2,0) {bla};

        \node at (0,2) {B};
        \node[none] at (2,2) {B};

        \draw (0,4) -- node[right] {C} (0,5);
        \draw[none] (0,4) -- node[right] {C} (0,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: As Percusse points out, it might be hard to make TeX actually *not draw* it, so maybe it's easier to ask how to *invisibly draw* it.

Comment: PDF objects and TikZ operands are not organically connected. Some options are just turned on and stay as such. And pgfkeys are not commutative so the last one wins. So the implementation can be quite cumbersome of such. That's also the reason why we don't have `return to default style`. Because all keys must be swept to reset everything. Instead draw your picture with that option in mind and append `none` to stuff that you want to turn off. Then you can activate/deactivate on demand.

Comment: @Percusse, right, but thankfully TikZ styles are sort of scoped. Also, I'm not really interested in *not drawing* the objects, but rather *"drawing them invisibly"*.

Comment: Please provide an MWE rather than expecting people to start from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

I would define a style and **either** use it in all the constructions where you want this capability **or** scope the portions of the diagram which you want to turn off visible and invisible construction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bla/.pic={\node {A};},
                  none/.style={text opacity=0,opacity=0,fill opacity=0},
                  my path/.style={},
                  %<line 1>%my path/.style={every path/.style={none},none},
                  %<line 2>%my path
                  ]

  \pic at (0,0) {bla};
  \pic at (2,0) {bla};

  \begin{scope}[line width=8pt,draw=red,my path]
    \node (SB1) at (0,2) {SB1};
    \node (SB2) at (2,2) {SB2};
    \draw (SB1) -- (SB2);
  \end{scope}

  \draw  (0,4) -- node[right] (C1) {C1} (0,5);
  \draw  (2,4) -- node[right] (C2) {C2} (2,5);

  \draw[my path] (SB1) -- (SB2);

  \draw[red,line width=2pt] (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.west);

  \fill[fill=blue!30,my path] (current bounding box.north east) rectangle (current bounding box.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By uncommenting `%<line 1>%` you can get the style applied where you want it.  By uncommenting `%<line 2>%` you can more universally apply it.